# Conditional Conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to filter a query based on a conditional condition, for example if `ProjectId equals 1` then filter based on some condition otherwise, another diffrerent condition:

something that- if possible in SQL- would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Commits] 
WHERE CASE WHEN ProjectId=1 THEN (CommitsCount > 2) ELSE (Name LIKE 'R%') END
```

Example:

```
ProjectId   Name      CommitsCount
----------- --------- -----------
1           Ahmed     2
1           Ahmed     6
2           Kamel     10
3           Rami      NULL
```

The result I need from the query is:

```
ProjectId   Name      CommitsCount
----------- --------- -----------
1           Ahmed     6
3           Rami      NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` conditions in `where` clauses is not recommended.  One reason is that they impede optimization of the query.  Another is simply that they are not needed, so it make the conditions more complicated than necessary.

So I would recommend:

```
select c.*
from dbo.commits c
where (c.ProjectId = 1 and c.CommitsCount > 2) or
      (c.ProjectId <> 1 and c.Name = 'R&');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Commits] 
WHERE (CASE WHEN ProjectId  = 1 AND CommitsCount > 2 THEN 1
            WHEN ProjectId != 1 AND Name LIKE 'R%'   THEN 1
      END) = 1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4771d7ef578be582d1e55cd952d61ec7)**

`(Name ='R&')` => `Name LIKE 'R%'`

Comment: I've added an example, illustrating how should the result be

Comment: Oh thanks I have a mistake in my query (used `&` instead of `%`), great answer!